# Powershell create outlook mail with custom voting option

Tags: powershell, scripting, outlook

I have been trying to find answers with no luck if this is possible.

Is there a way to create an outlook email with custom voting options through powershell?

My goal is to have an automated script that sends email based on a criteria and have it sent with a custom voting options so that people can respond through a voting mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it by using the Outlook COM Object model.

```
#Open Outlook
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

#Create new Mail Message
$mail = $outlook.CreateItem(0)
$mail.To = 'user@someplace.com'
$mail.Subject = 'Test Voting'
$mail.Body = 'Test Voting Message'

#Add Voting options
$mail.VotingOptions = "Yes;No;Maybe"

#Send Message
$mail.Send()

#Exit Outlook
$outlook.Quit()
```